# Where is Notifications in OpenIdConnectOptions in .NET Core 1.0.0 RC2?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It looks like there is breaking change in RC2.

I was trying to set up the OpenId connect using this section of old code:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = Configuration.Get("AzureAd:ClientId");
    options.Authority = String.Format(Configuration.Get("AzureAd:AadInstance"), Configuration.Get("AzureAd:Tenant"));
    options.PostLogoutRedirectUri = Configuration.Get("AzureAd:PostLogoutRedirectUri");
    options.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
    };
});
```

But the lambda options setup is not available.

If I try to use a new `OpenIdConnectOptions`.

```
var clientId = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD:ClientId").Value;
var azureADInstance = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD:AzureADInstance").Value;
var tenant = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD:Tenant").Value;
var postLogoutRedirectUrl = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAD:PostLogoutRedirectUrl").Value;

var authority = $"{azureADInstance}{tenant}";
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUrl,

});
```

No `Notifications` is there. Anyone knows what is the new setup?

---

## Update

Based on the answer by Pinpoint, here is my updated code:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = clientId,
    Authority = authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUrl,
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
    }
});
```

and the `OnAuthenticationFailed` method is:

```
private static Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
{
    context.HandleResponse();
    context.Response.Redirect($"/Home/Error?message={context.Exception.Message}");
    return Task.FromResult(0);

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> No Notifications is there. Anyone knows what is the new setup?

The `Notifications` property was renamed to `Events` and `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications` is now named `OpenIdConnectEvents`.